Is there a way to prevent a page loading if a custom Certificate Authority is used
Take as an example a Bank.
A bank website has sensitive information that they want to ensure remain encrypted. However, they know that people are likely to access their bank website from work, who may have installed custom CAs on their machine as part of an SSL inspection utility, so in theory there may be logs stored insecurely on work servers that could disclose sensitive information.  Or, maybe they're using Public Wifi and ignore the warnings about the certificate being invalid on instruction from the helpful card included with the password.
Is there any kind of mechanism to block access in this scenario, so that resigning the traffic could be detected and blocked, maybe even a message saying what happened?
Key pinning is dead
Expect-CT is dead
What else do we have?
Obviously, any traffic intercepted can be modified and safeguards removed, but we could at least try?
